# Errors with models in django, creating events registration app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i am creating django `app` that allows users to register to different events.
I created one Registration model in `.models` and added specific `views` but i have got some model errors. Wondered if anyone could help out a little?
I am also not 100% sure if i have done all code correctly because i am quite new to django.
Thanks a lot!
Here is my model file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
import datetime


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    hardness_level = models.TextField(max_length=20, default='easy')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField('location', max_length=150)
    info = models.TextField()
    starts = models.DateTimeField('Starts')
    ends = models.DateTimeField('Ends')
    arrive_when = models.DateTimeField('Arrival time', null=True, blank=True)
    arrive_where = models.CharField('Arrival location', null=True, max_length=150, blank=True)
    registration_starts = models.DateTimeField('Registration start')
    registration_limit = models.IntegerField('Guest limit',
                                             default=0,
                                             choices=[(0, u"No limit")] + list(zip(range(1, 100), range(1, 100))),
                                             on_delete=models.CASCADE())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "event"
        verbose_name_plural = "events"
        ordering = ['-starts']

    def __str__(self):
        if self.starts.date() != self.ends.date():
            return u"%s, %s - %s" % (self.title,
                                         self.starts.strftime("%a %H:%M"),
                                         self.ends.strftime("%a %H:%M"))
        else:
            return u"%s, %s - %s" % (self.title,
                                         self.starts.strftime("%H:%M"),
                                         self.ends.strftime("%H:%M"))

    def get_registrations(self):
        return EventRegistration.objects.filter(event=self)

    permissions = (
        ("add_training", "Can add training"),
    )


class EventRegistration(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Post,verbose_name='Event')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name='Attendee')
    time_registered = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Attendee for event'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Attendees for events'
        ordering = ['time_registered', ]
        unique_together = ('event', 'user')

    def add_user_to_list_of_attendees(self, user):
        registration = EventRegistration.objects.create(user=user,
                                                        event=self,
                                                        time_registered=timezone.now())
        registration.add()

    def remove_user_from_list_of_attendees(self, user):
        registration = EventRegistration.objects.get(user=user, event=self)
        registration.delete()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id is None and self.time_registered is None:
            self.time_registered = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(EventRegistration, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here my views file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)


def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()              #listi andmetest, saadud kasutajalt paneb contenti sisse
    }
    return render(request, 'training/home.html', context)


def event_add_attendance(request, pk):
    this_event = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    this_event.add_user_to_list_of_attendees(user=request.user)
    return redirect('events:detail', pk=pk)


def event_cancel_attendance(request, pk):
    this_event = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    this_event.remove_user_from_list_of_attendees(request.user)
    return redirect('events:detail', pk=pk)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'training/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
```

And finally urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView
    )
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='training-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', views.PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='training-about'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/useradded', views.event_add_attendance(), name='add-user'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/userdeleted', views.event_cancel_attendance(), name='delete-user'),
]
```

Comment: Where is error message ?

Comment: Error is: TypeError: CASCADE() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'collector', 'field', 'sub_objs', and 'using'

Comment: It should be ```models.CASCADE``` - without the ```()```

Comment: Please add your error message to your question

Comment: Then when i remove () arises new error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_delete'

Comment: You're correct, on_delete is only for ```ForeignKeys```. Take that out of your ```IntegerField``` declaration

Comment: @AustinRoose you have `IntegerField`. you don't need `on_delete` at all ! just remove it

Comment: But the __init__() error is still there?

Comment: Oh i see i haveunder EventRegistration class two ForeignKeys, i need to add on_delete there

Comment: Sorry, but what i should do with this error: TypeError: event_add_attendance() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'request' and 'pk'? Something with views

Comment: Got it, removed () from paths in views.py file.

Comment: But which fields must have default value?

Comment: Because i have error: You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'ends' to post without a default

Comment: fields are manadatory by default, meaning you need to provide a value if you want to save the model. If you provide a default value by ```default=some_value``` this value will be used if you don't provide a value. If you set ```null=True``` the field is not mandatory, you can leave it empty and do not need a default value. Your error indicates that you are missing a value for ```ends``` when creating a ```Post```.

Comment: Thank you, i made some changes and now my error is, “easy” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]

Comment: Even if i change DateTimeFields in my model to null=True